# Dell XPS 9570 showing BIOS updates in Ubuntu only (not Windows)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios, dell-xps

From Windows (11 22H2), neither **Dell Update**, **SupportAssist**, nor the **Dell Support Website** detect any available BIOS updates. The site also only lists a single manual entry, which is for the one that is already installed (*1.27* Sep 2022).

However, `fwupdmgr` from Ubuntu detects three updates - the most current and two previous ones (*1.31*, *1.30*, *1.29*).

Is there a chance any of these versions haven't yet been officially tested and/or approved for Windows, and is why they are not visible from there? Could updating pose a risk to Windows' stability?

According to the `/etc/fwupd/` config files `fwupdmgr` appears to be using LVFS ([Linux Vendor Firmware Service](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/)), so I'm confident in the firmware's authenticity though uncertain of its Windows support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The
[XPS 15 9570 Support page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/xps-15-9570-laptop/drivers)
lists only version 1.27.0 as the last version.

The Windows software is correct - the Linux software probably wrongly
detects your computer model.

My advice : Do NOT install any other version than the one proposed
by the Dell software on Windows. Using the wrong BIOS can brick
your computer.

Comment: The close version numbering had me gloss this possibility over. Thanks!

Comment: Running `fwupdmgr block-firmware`, just need to find checksum

Comment: [How do I block updating a specific device with fwupd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/700287/how-do-i-block-updating-a-specific-device-with-fwupd)

Comment: If your version of Ubuntu is up to date it might be worth raising that as a bug.